# href overrides ng-click in Angular.js

Tags: html, angularjs, anchor, markup

When both, href and ng-click attributes are defined:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Sign out</a>
```

the `href` attribute takes precedence over ng-click.

I am looking for a way to raise priority of ng-click.

`href` is required for Twitter Bootstrap, I can't remove it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "href is required for Twitter Bootstrap"? Which part of it? CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: The Twitter Bootstrap nav "widget" is setup to use links, if you add a button to it, even one that's styled to look like a link it breaks the styling of the navigation. It's probably not semantic HTML but @sketchfemme's solution does what I (and probably Paul) want it to do.

Comment: Ignore everything I said, navbar works perfectly with buttons if you use the right HTML and classes. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: You should accept the answer by Mithu, which is to use an empty URL

Comment: @Paul The original poster asked how to get a <a href> to not navigate. The accepted answer says to switch to a button. Although that works it is not the solution to the problem, especially if like myself you are forced to use  <a href> because it's a bootstrap menu or something. The correct solution to this specific question is to use an empty url <a href="" ng-click="whatever()">Log out</a> - I tested it and can confirm it works. Thankfully someone else provided the correct answer or I'd still be stuck.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should probably just use a button tag if you don't need a uri.

Comment: Yes, if you can elaborate on how Twitter Bootstrap requires it, maybe I can help more.

Comment: How does this work with search engines?  I am using AngularJS routing and need to maintain state in a service so for all of my internal application links I use $location, but removing href make it impossible for search engines to follow along the site.

Comment: buttons can't have other element inside them, so for styling, you wouldn't want to do that - if you need things inside of it.

Answer (score 246):

This example from the angular documentation site just does `href` without even assigning it to an empty string:

```
[<a href ng-click="colors.splice($index, 1)">X</a>]
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: When I try this all of the links appear to be visited, which is not the behaviour I'm after. The other way (`href="#"`) causes a page reload, which is also wrong.

Comment: This makes IE9 not to show a hand cursor. Using `href=""` solves it.

Comment: @juampy, the hand over the link can be handled with CSS.  This answer given is the official AngularJS way to do it.

Comment: The # will get treated like hash link.

Comment: `<a href="javscript:void(0)" ng-click="logout()">Sign out</a>` will serve you well too

Answer (score 90):

You can simply prevent the default behavior of the click event directly in your template.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();logout()" />
```

Per the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-),

> Directives like ngClick and ngFocus expose a $event object within the scope of that expression.

Comment: This is a great solution. If you have an href, you can right click to open it in a new tab, but on left click it calls ng-click. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Once again an excellent answer. Both left and right click work

Comment: Worked great for allowing Bootstrap carousel controls without triggering routing. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! I can continue with links and get more index in Google and use ng-click to call in Ajax. Thanks.

Comment: Great solution, quick and useful. Thanks!

Comment: You saved me.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 74):

Here is another solution :

```
<a href="" ng-click="logout()">Sign out</a>
```

i.e. Just remove the # from the href attribute

Comment: For the question asked, this should be the solution. Worked on Angular 1.1.5 as well

Comment: It seems <a href="" ng-click=""> will prevent the ng-click in Android 2.3.x browser. I finally use <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="">

Comment: Duckegg's suggestion is the best one

Answer (score 28):

Just one more hint. If you need real URL (to support browser accessibility) you can do the following:

template:

```
<a ng-href="{{link}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); linkClicked(link)">{{link}}</a>
```

directive:

```
$scope.linkClicked = function(link){
    // your code here
    $location.path(link);
};
```

In this way your code in linkClicked() will have chance to execute before navigating to the link

Comment: This solution works and only changes the left click behaviour, right click stays intact (context menu), including the possibility to a link in href. So that is a more general solution compared to TooMuchTenacious, which actually answers the question more directly.

Answer (score 22):

In Angular, [`<a>`s are directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a). As such, if you have an empty `href` or no `href`, Angular will call `event.preventDefault`.

From the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js#L3):

```
    element.on('click', function(event){
      // if we have no href url, then don't navigate anywhere.
      if (!element.attr(href)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/svnjb7UAMETe5mf2iWiU?p=preview) demonstrating the missing `href` scenario.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me in IE 9 and AngularJS v1.0.7:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
```

Thanks to [duckeggs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939385/href-overrides-ng-click-in-angular-js#comment28887838_15794760) for the working solution!

Comment: Works, the link doesn't change your url and isn't marked as visited. Best answer!

Answer (score 13):

There are so many answers for this question here but it seems there is a bit of confusion about what's actually going on here.

Firstly, your premise

> *"href overrides ng-click in Angular.js"*

is wrong. What is actually happening is that after your click, the click event is first handled by angular(defined by `ng-click` directive in angular 1.x and `click` in angular 2.x+) and then it continues to propagate(which eventually triggers the browser to navigate to the url defined with `href` attribute).(See [this](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) for more about event propagation in javascript)

If you want to avoid this, then you should cancel the event propagation using the [The Event interface's `preventDefault()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
<a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();logout()" />
```

(This is pure javascript functionality and nothing to do with angular)

Now, this will already solve your problem but this is not the optimal solution. Angular, rightfully, promotes the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). With this solution, your html template is mixed with the javascript logic. You should try to avoid this as much as possible and put your logic into your angular controller. So a better way would be

```
<a href="#" ng-click="logout($event)" />
```

And in your logout() method:

```
logout($event) {
   $event.preventDefault();
   ...
}
```

Now the click event will not reach the browser, so it will not try to load the link pointed by `href`. (However note that if the user right clicks on the link and directly opens the link, then there won't be a click event at all. Instead it will directly load the url pointed by the `href` attribute.)

Regarding the comments about visited link color in the browsers. Again this has nothing to do with angular, if your `href="..."` points to a visited url by your browser by default the link color will be different. This is controlled by [CSS :visited Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp), you can modify your css to override this behaviour:

```
a {
   color:pink;
}
```

**PS1**:

Some answers suggest to use:

```
<a href .../>
```

`href` is an angular directive. When your template is processed by angular this will be converted to

```
<a href="" .../>
```

Those two ways are essentially the same.

Answer (score 5):

Just write ng-click before href ..It worked for me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module("module",[])
.controller("controller",function($scope){
  
  $scope.func =function(){
    console.log("d");
  }
  
})</script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="module" ng-controller="controller">
    <h1>Hello ..</h1>
    <a ng-click="func()" href="someplace.html">Take me there</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to remove "#" from href. Following works with Angularjs 1.2.10

```
<a href="#/" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
<div ng-init="myVar = 'www.thesoftdesign'">
        <h1>Tutorials</h1>
        <p>Go to <a ng-href="{{myVar}}">{{myVar}}</a> to learn!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add for you an example that work for me and you can change it as you want.

I add the bellow code inside my controller.

```
     $scope.showNumberFct = function(){
        alert("Work!!!!");
     }
```

and for my view page I add the bellow code.

```
<a  href="" ng-model="showNumber" ng-click="showNumberFct()" ng-init="showNumber = false" >Click Me!!!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try redirecting inside the logout function itself? For example, say your logout function is as follows

```
$scope.logout = function()
{
  $scope.userSession = undefined;
  window.location = "http://www.yoursite.com/#"
}
```

Then you can just have

```
<a ng-click="logout()">Sign out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
<a href="#" ng-click="logout(event)">Logout</a>

 $scope.logout = function(event)


 {
event.preventDefault();
alert("working..");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//for dynamic elements - if you want it in ng-repeat do below code

angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key) {
     //add new value to object
    value.new_url  = "your url";
});

 <div ng-repeat="row in data"><a ng-href="{{ row.url_content }}"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<a href (click)="logout()">
   <i class="icon-power-off"></i>
   Logout
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="#">
       <span ng-click="logout()"> Sign out </span>
 </a>
```

I did like this and it worked for me.