# angular: state change looses URL at second click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have 4 states, each representing a different visualization. The first visualization is a map, the second to fourth are pie charts.

The default is the map visualization. I have three icons showing always the other 3 possible visualizations.

Each of the state is actually a nested state. The first state is "`root.map`", then we have "`root.vis1`", "`root.vis2`", and "`root.vis3`".

When I initially load the default "`root.map`" visualization, all is fine first. Then I click on an icon, and all works fine, the visualization changes. The URL in the browser becomes "`localhost:3000/#/root/vis2`" for example. But when I click again, although the visualization correctly changes to the chosen one, I loose the path in the browser, and it becomes "`localhost:3000/#`".

What could be causing this? I'd like the URL in the browser to always reflect the current URL (so it can be bookmarked or shared).

The state provider config:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "views/home.html",      
    })
    .state('root', {
      abstract: true,
      url: "/root",
      cache: false,
      templateUrl: "views/root.html"
    })
    .state('root.map', {
        url: "/map",
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "views/map.html",
        resolve: {
          //some resolve code
        }
    })
 .state('root.vis1', {
        url: "/vis1",
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "views/vis.html"
    })
    .state('root.vis2', {
        url: "/vis2",
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "views/vis.html"
    })
    .state('root.vis3', {
        url: "/vis3",
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "views/vis.html"
      });
  }
```

The icons:

```
<a class="inline vis-icons" href="#" ng-click="set_visualization('vis2');"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
```

The `set_visualization` function in the controller:

```
$scope.set_visualization = function(visualization) {
    $scope.current_vis = visualization;
    $state.transitionTo('root.' + visualization);
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Do the other links (like, to `vis1`, etc...) have `href="#"` in them? If you go to `vis2` first and then back to `vis1`, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: why are you using `$state.TransitionTo` instead of `$state.go`?

Comment: don't use `href="#"` without `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<a class="inline vis-icons" href="" ng-click="set_visualization('vis2');">
```

Or

```
<a class="inline vis-icons" ng-click="set_visualization('vis2');">
```

See:
[href overrides ng-click in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939385/href-overrides-ng-click-in-angular-js)