# Ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a controller, in which I start an http request and once the request is completed, I call another view and then used `ng-click`.But My `ng-click` is not working .

here is my code.

```
app.controller('listuser', function ($scope,$http,$log,$window) {
        $scope.userdetail = {};
        return $http({
                 method: 'POST',
                 url: 'apisource.php',

            })
            .then(function (results) {

                $scope.data=results.data;
                return $scope.data;
            });

         $scope.douserdetail = function(user) {
             alert('test');
        };

    });
```

```html
<tr data-ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td>
        <input type="hidden"  name="id" ng-model="userdetail.id" value="{{x.id}}" />
        <a href='' ng-click="douserdetail(userdetail)" class="user-link">{{x.First_Name}}{{x.Last_time}}</a>
        <span class="user-subhead">{{x.Phd_University}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can u create one fiddle link?

Comment: How do you create view?

Comment: "I call another view and then used ng-click" What does this mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939385/href-overrides-ng-click-in-angular-js

Comment: It looks like your controller is returning on line 3 so no code beyond is executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a `return` in the controller on line 3 of what you are showing so no code beyond the return statement is executing, try this:

```
app.controller('listuser', function ($scope,$http,$log,$window) {
    $scope.userdetail = {};
    $scope.data = [];

    var init = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'apisource.php',

        })
            .then(function (results) {
                $scope.data=results.data;
            });
    };
    init();

    $scope.douserdetail = function(user) {
        alert('test');
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use a div or button type elements,not 'a' tag.
change a tag to div or something ,it will work

```
<div ng-click="douserdetail(userdetail)" class="user-link">{{x.First_Name}}{{x.Last_time}}</div>
```

Comment: are you sure? I would be suprised if this works, even in the AngularJS official documentation it states that you can put an ng-click inside an a tag.

Comment: An empty href attribute, which he already has, should also work

Comment: @PankajParkar we have to remove href="" in 'a' tag  ,otherwise it will not take click ,am i right?

Comment: Could also just preventdefault, but still I'm not sure it should be necessary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939385/href-overrides-ng-click-in-angular-js