# AngularJS and Mongoose deleting document not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

This may not be a perfect solution, but I have a `ProductModel` where some products have a path to a locally stored image, `image01Path`.  When I want to delete a product I am trying to do firstly delete the image from local storage, then trying to delete the product document.

My 'delete' service initially looks like -

```
app.delete('/api/product/:id', function(req, res){
    ProductModel.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).exec(function(err, product){
        if (!err){ 
            if(product.image01Path){
                fs.unlink('public/' + product.image01Path);
            }
            ProductModel.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).remove().exec().then(function successCallback(data){
                res.send(200);
            }, function errorCallback(){

            }); 
        } else {throw err;}
    });

})
```

Which is being called by -

```
$scope.delete = function(product){
       $http.delete('/api/product/' + $routeParams.id).then(function successCallback(){
           $location.url('/home');
       }, function errorCallback(){

       })
   }
```

My issue is, even though I believe I have the redirect to `home` only happening on success of the deletion of the document, when my Home controller makes another rest call to get the updated list of products I am still seeing the deleted product.  When I then refresh the page I am finally seeing the correct list of products.  Where am I going wrong?

My Home controller -

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location){   
    $http.get('/api/products').then(function successCallback(products){
        $scope.products = products.data;       
    }, function errorCallback(){

    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue - I had both `href="#"` and `ng-click="delete(product)"` in the view.  It looks like the href was redirecting me to `home` which was making the rest call for a list of products, as per my Home controller above, before the product had been deleted in the back end.

Looking at this question - [href overrides ng-click in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939385/href-overrides-ng-click-in-angular-js) I see what I should have done.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because fs is async as well. So you'll need to pass in a callback into the fs.unlink (rough coding):

```
app.delete('/api/product/:id', function (req, res) {
ProductModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).exec(function (err, product) {
    if (!err) {
        if (product.image01Path) {
            fs.unlink('public/' + product.image01Path, function (err) {

                if (!err) {
                    ProductModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).remove().exec().then(function successCallback(data) {
                        res.send(200);
                    }, function errorCallback() {

                    });
                } else {
                    //fs.unlink failed
                }
            });
        } else {
            //Product.image not found
        }
    } else {
        //Error in finding product
        throw err;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - I had tried this out, but doesnt seem to solve the issue.  Note the file is pretty standalone and should be able to be remove async, the product only has a String path to where the file should be located

Answer (score 0):

unlink method from fs is Asynchronous as mentioned [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback), so you have you options.

Use the Synchronous unlink:

```
fs.unlinkSync(path)
```

Or use the callback param in Asynchronous unlink, so it will be:

```
if(product.image01Path){
    fs.unlink('public/' + product.image01Path, function(){
        ProductModel.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).remove().exec().then(function successCallback(data){
            res.send(200);
        }, function errorCallback(){
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - I had tried this out, but doesnt seem to solve the issue.  Note the file is pretty standalone and should be able to be remove async, the product only has a String path to where the file should be located