# href is overridden by ng-click - mobile

Tags: html, angularjs, redirect

i have following structure

```
<div>
  <figure with ng-click>
    <a with href>
      <img></img>
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

And i am facing problem with redirection. Ng-click is doing some analytics things but it looks it prevents from href. Actually when i put my mouse on fire i can get redirected, but it is not working on mobile device. I tried to wrap also figure, but no success at all. I also tried to put ng-click inside *a* element, the same. I tried ng-href, same result.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [href overrides ng-click in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939385/href-overrides-ng-click-in-angular-js)

Comment: do you use [`ngTouch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) module?

Comment: yes i have. Do it have some corelation