# Bootstrap navbar is not collapsing in AngularJS environment

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my project, I used Bootstrap Nav bar for navigation and also AngularJS as the framework. In desktop view, it's working fine. But in mobile view, the Nav bar is not working properly. It's not auto collapsing when we click on a link.

This is my Nav bar code:

```
<nav style="padding:0;margin:0;border:0;" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="isCollapsed = true" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/" id="mainLogo">
                <img style="max-width:200px;" src="img/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse" ng-class="{collapse: isCollapsed}">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#/" class="show-submenu">Home </a>

                </li>
                <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#/collection/brand/model/type/year" class="show-submenu">Our Collection </a>

                </li>
                <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#/about" class="show-submenu">About us </a>

                </li>
                <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#/contact" class="show-submenu">Contact us</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I tried many solutions and still no good.

You can check the real example [here](http://159.65.85.91/vms-website/).

I tried some Angular code samples and also JS based solutions. Nothing works for me. Can you please provide me a working NavBar sample with Angular. 
My Angular version is 1.3 and Bootstrap version is 3.x

Comment: it's best not to use jQuery with AngularJS, it's not part of the digest cycle. AngularJS can do DOM manipulations in directives that use JQLite. Simplest solution: switch jQuery Bootstrap to [`ui-bootstrap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** it`s a very hacky solution but it should work pretty well.

As said in the comments it's hard to combine both logics.

Just use `ng-click="isCollapsed = false"` event on every navbar element:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse" ng-class="{collapse: isCollapsed}">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="#/" ng-click="isCollapsed = false" class="show-submenu">Home </a>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="#/collection/brand/model/type/year" ng-click="isCollapsed = false" class="show-submenu">Our Collection </a>

        </li>
        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="#/about" ng-click="isCollapsed = false" class="show-submenu">About us </a>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="#/contact" ng-click="isCollapsed = false" class="show-submenu">Contact us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you have trouble with the combination of `href` and `ng-click` you can have a look here [href overrides ng-click in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939385/href-overrides-ng-click-in-angular-js). Basically you can also move everything inside a function like `collapseAndMove(href)` and doing the routing and collapse stuff there.